# Hide application title bar in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, titlebar

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 I noticed that some applications have a big white title bar separate from the application's main toolbar. For example, here's maximized PyCharm after the upgrade:

[image: pycharm title bar]

This happened to a bunch of apps (i.e. VS Code, Spotify), while other apps (Gedit, Firefox, Chrome) are not affected.

I found this blog post that offers a custom solution for VS Code https://leimao.github.io/blog/VS-Code-Hide-Window-Title-Bar/ but I'm wondering if there's a system-wide way to fix this. Or at least a solution that works for JetBrains IDEs.